# How to parse the below mentioned xml in android and store it in the class?

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I'm having an requirement where i need to parse the below xml and store it in class.

```
<syncgroupsettings>
        <syncgroupset id = "sgMS" labelid = "lblMS" enabled = "YES" default = "OFF">
            <syncgroup syncgroupname = "VISITS"/>
            <syncgroup syncgroupname = "CUSTOMERS"/>
        </syncgroupset>

        <syncgroupset id = "sgAS" labelid = "lblAS" enabled = "YES" default = "ON">
            <syncgroup syncgroupname = "SALESDOCS"/>
            <syncgroup syncgroupname = "ANALYTICS"/>
        </syncgroupset>
    </syncgroupsettings>
```

So far what i have done was, i used to get the node value and simply adding it to arraylist of hashmap as shown below for other xml.

```
public class XmlParser {

    private static final String ns = null;

    /** This is the only function need to be called from outside the class */
    public static List<ArrayList<HashMap>> parse(Reader reader)
            throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        try{
            List<ArrayList<HashMap>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap>>();
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(reader);
            parser.nextTag();           
            return readLabels(parser);
        }finally{

        }
    }        

    /** This method read each country in the xml data and add it to List */
    private static List<ArrayList<HashMap>> readLabels(XmlPullParser parser)
            throws XmlPullParserException,IOException {

        List<ArrayList<HashMap>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap>>();

        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "xml");

        while(parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG){
            if(parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                continue;
            }

            String name = parser.getName();
            if(name.equals("labels")){
                //do nothing
            }
            else if(name.equals("label"))
             {
                 list.add(readLabel(parser));
             }
            else
            {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }       
        return list;
    }

    /** This method read a country and returns its corresponding HashMap construct */
    private static ArrayList<HashMap> readLabel(XmlPullParser parser)
            throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "label");

        String labelid = parser.getAttributeValue(ns, "id");
        String textlan = "";
        String textval="";

        ArrayList<HashMap> al=new ArrayList<HashMap>();
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        while(parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG){
            if(parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG){

                continue;
            }

            String name = parser.getName();
             if(name.equals("text")) {
                textlan = parser.getAttributeValue(ns,"language");
                textval = parser.getAttributeValue(ns,"value");
                 String details =   "language : " + textlan  + "value : " + textval;
                 hm.put(labelid,details );
                 al.add(hm);
                 readText(parser);
             }
            else
             {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }
        return al;
    }


    /** Process Capital tag in the xml data */    
    private static void readText(XmlPullParser parser)
            throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "text");
        parser.nextTag();
    }


    private static void skip(XmlPullParser parser)
            throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        int depth = 1;
        while (depth != 0) {
            switch (parser.next()) {
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                depth--;
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                depth++;
                break;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

But for this particular xml, i need to store it in the class. Could you please help me with this regard.